# getting rid of the 0 from the middle of the list in index match return in excel

Tags: excel, indexing, match

I have a similar to below list in excel column D:

Project Plan Sheet

- Kevin
- Alex
- Max
- empty
- Kevin
- Alex
- Max
- empty
- John
- Alex
- Max
- empty

And from the above list I want to get a list without the empty cells and with only names appearing once in cell J59 to down:

Output sheet:

- Kevin
- Alex
- Max
- John

I use the index match formula similar to below on the output sheet J59:

`=INDEX('Project Plan'!D9:D100; MATCH(0; COUNTIF($J$58:J58;'Project Plan'!D9:D100);0))`

When I dragged the formula down, I get such a result:

- Kevin
- Alex
- Max
- 0
- John

How can I get rid of this 0 from the middle of my list?

Comment: What version of Excel are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
=INDEX('Project plan'!$D$9:$D$100; MATCH(0; COUNTIF($J$58:J58;'Project plan'!$D$9:$D$100&"");0))
```

Comment: Hi @Rory, this certainly helped with getting rid of the 0 from the middle of the list but now I still don't get the full list, e.g. John is not showing up in the list. It gives me the list of the people until the first empty cell and then the rest is 0.

Comment: It works fine for me. Did you array enter it with Ctrl+Shift+Enter? And add the $ signs to the ranges?

Comment: That formula shouldn't return **0** under any circumstances. Can you put a workbook somewhere for me to look at?

Comment: Ah,  sorry eventually your formula works just fine, the reason I was having an issue was because in the cell above where i use the code (J58) I had the word "Name", as soon as I deleted it formula returned the right list. But why is this an issue,, could that be solved?

Comment: Your formula is fairly flawed to be fair. Does it matter what order the results come back in?

Answer (score 0):

Note that with the latest version of Excel, with the new `FILTER` and `UNIQUE` functions, you can accomplish this with:

```
=UNIQUE(FILTER(your_range,your_range<>""))
```